# Story points for bug fixing tasks: Is it suitable for Scrum?

Tags: agile, scrum, bug, user-story

I'm just wondering if we should assign story points to bug fixing tasks or not. JIRA, our issues-tracking software, does not have story point field for *Bug* type issues (it's only for *Story*s and *Epic*s).

Should we add the *Bug* issue type to the applicable issue types of the *Story Points* field?  What are the pros and cons? Would it be suitable for Scrum?

Comment: FYI, although bugs can't be pointed by default, [that can be changed in Jira](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/88674/not-able-to-enter-estimates-for-bugs-and-enhancement-issue-types-in-greenhopper).

Answer (score 63):

Ideally, your software should be bug-free after each iteration, and fixing bugs should be part of each sprint, so the work required to fix bugs should be considered when assigning story points (i.e., a task that is more likely to produce bugs should have more story points assigned to it).

In reality, however, bugs surface post-deployment all the time, no matter how rigid your testing; when that happens, removing the bug is just another change, a feature if you will. There is no fundamental difference between a bug report and a feature request in this context: in both cases, the application shows a certain behavior, and the user (or some other stakeholder) would like to see it changed.

From a business perspective, bugfixes and features are also the same, really: either you do it (scenario B), or you don't (scenario A); both scenarios have costs and benefits attached, and a decent business person will just weigh them up and go with whatever earns them more profit (long-term or short-term depending on business strategy).

So yes, by all means, assign story points to bugs. How else are you going to prioritize bugs vs. features, and bugs against bugs? You need some measure of development effort for both, and it better be comparable.

The biggest problem with this is that bugfixes are often harder to estimate: 90% or more of the actual effort lies in finding the cause; once you have found it, you can come up with an accurate estimate, but it is almost impossible to judge how long the search will take. I've even seen a fair share of bugs where most of the time was spent just trying to *reproduce* the bug. On the other hand, depending on the nature of the bug, it is often possible to narrow down the search with some minimal research before making an estimate.

Comment: I was in the middle of writing an answer that ended up being nearly identical to yours.  I like your explanation better.

Comment: The only problem I have is your fourth passage. You don't prioritize based on story points (at least, I've never seen that, and it seems rather silly). You prioritize based on business value added and use story points to determine how many of the stories you can complete in your timeboxed iteration. It's entirely possible to take a less prioritized story into an earlier iteration because the ones above it are too large to fit within the projected velocity.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: OK, let me rephrase that. What I meant is that story points are required to judge the benefit of any change vs. its development effort. Of course the benefit is just as important in prioritizing as the effort.

Comment: I like the general notion of your answer. We have solved the prioritization/ranking issue by separating bugs into a separate backlog and creating a ratio (regular backlog to bug backlog) to deal with what you are describing in the last two paragraphs. Your last paragraph describes the problem inherent to bug fixing quite well. And it is also the reason why we are not doing story point estimation for bugs. I have expanded on why your solution approach failed for us in my answer and how we got out of it.

Answer (score 27):

You **should not** give points to bug resolution. Consider the fact that the bug comes forth from a story where the developers **already earned points** for completing the story. It should not receive points **again** where it actually *shouldn't have earned the points* to begin with.

Bug fixing should have a **negative effect** on velocity. Otherwise dropping quality ends up being rewarded with an unaffected or even increased velocity!

Perhaps a useful link:

http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/01/story-points-to-bugs

Comment: I understand your arguments about creating a positive environment for developers to write buggy code and having meaningless velocity, but keep in mind that bugs found in a feature after the sprint has been accepted means that the testers made a mistake in not catching these bugs before acceptance.  Furthermore completing user stories should not be a race to begin with, if a developer is completing many more user stories in a sprint than scheduled, that means he is not estimating the story effort in points very well. With that metric, developers look good just by over-estimating all the time.

Comment: @maple_shaft Acceptance is not about bugs, story acceptance is about features delivered. Or value delivered. It's not about programming errors. Typically testing is part of the definition of done, so also part of the points granted. If testing missed a correctness or programming error it unjustly claimed points.

Comment: The velocity (measured in story points per sprint) measures how much stuff the team can implement in a sprint. I'm sure every product owner keeps track of, and is much more interested in, how much business value the team produces. Business value doesn't get inflated from giving bug fixes story points.

Comment: @buhb story points say nothing about business value. A 5 point story could have 100 business value. A 100 point story could have 1 business value. It expresses effort not business value.

Comment: @Tungano: Exactly. That's why assigning points to bug fixes doesn't give a strong incentive to build buggy software.

Comment: @buhb A broken basket checkout feature that used to work is loss of value. Fixing it is restoration of value, not adding value.

Comment: @Tungano `If testing missed a correctness or programming error it unjustly claimed points` This is exactly my point, they made a mistake in judging the business value of a buggy feature. Or maybe not! Much of the time there is a moderator or minor bug with a feature that requires much more time to address than allowed in the sprint, meaning they accept the business value for what the feature is, however their is stil business value for a stakeholder in fixing the bug, however minor so a new user story is created.

Comment: The inflated velocity from including bug fixes causes another problem: it destroys your ability to use velocity to project into the future. Velocity should be a measure of how quickly the team can accomplish the work they set out to do, not a measure of how much work it actually was.

Comment: @maple_shaft "bugs found in a feature after the sprint has been accepted means testers made a mistake in not catching these bugs before acceptance" -- or developers made a mistake injecting the bug in the first place, or the product owner made a mistake not understanding customer's actual needs when articulating the story, or .... A defect can be injected in lots of different places by lots of different people.  You can't test in quality.

Comment: The bug should be considered a new feature if the original ask has been accepted and closed. Mainly because the original feature should be considered a sunk effort

Comment: You leave a lot out in your answer. What if the bugs were due to an incorrect spec from above? What if the bugs have nothing to do with the features most recently developed? What if the bugs are due to version upgrades? In my experience, bugs can arise from many places, from parts of the code base constructed in various points in time, by developers who may not even be employed at the company anymore. They don't necessarily arise from poorly executed features from the previous sprint.

Comment: Additionally, unless I've missed something of grave importance during my career, points are a tool used to help in estimation, not as trophies to be fought for: they're not shiny little badges we wear on our shirts like those golden stars we got in elementary school.

Answer (score 21):

Estimating bugs with points is inherently difficult as already pointed out in other answers and yes the ideal solution is that **bugs found in a feature AFTER the sprint has been accepted should be considered new features**.

This difficulty in point estimation for bugs however is one of many reasons that Agile PM software packages allow for tasks and bugs to be estimated in hours, because it takes dilligence and experience to become skilled at point estimation.  Many projects run into significant problems with properly determining velocity, so many Agile projects use points to determine what stories make it into the sprint, however they use hours when calculating the **burndown chart**.

It seems counter intuitive but manageable as long as hours estimation is not used as a factor in determining the sprint commitment.  Overcommittment will naturally lead to missed or incomplete features or overtime, so over time all involved are forced to get better at point estimation, at which point estimating hours on tasks and bugs slowly become a meaningless metric.

Comment: To me, "hours" == "human effort". If story points represent ranges of hours, then there is, on the face of it, zero difference between using story points and using hour estimates. But furthermore, both conceptually and from my own experience, using hour estimates is counterproductive in all cases, because it bestows high values of precision to variables that are only known very imprecisely.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend treating the bug as a user story and assigning it a number of points. I wouldn't necessarily write it in the format of "As a X, I want to Y so that Z" as is common with user stories - I'd write it more as "As a X, when I Y, Z happens, but Z' is the expected behavior".

The advantage of this is that it allows you to prioritize bug fixes right along side new feature requests. The truth is that sometimes, a new feature is more important than fixing a bug. However, it also allows you to properly size the work required, allowing you to fit it into a sprint when you have the capability of doing so.

One thing to keep in mind that it might be difficult to estimate the effort that is required to fix a bug. It could involve multiple components that interact with each other, requiring someone to become very familiar with the interactions of large pieces of the system or multiple people to work on the fix.

Answer (score 6):

Estimating stories is based on the notion that, with time, a team earns experience in resolving them. With it accuracy is improved and velocity can be established to measure a teams speed. A perfect methodology for establishing reliable prognoses for future sprints.

Bugs are a fact of life for a software development company. While I agree that bugs should all be caught during the development of a story, accepting that this cannot be achieved at all times, should be something that every team should plan for. Instead of stubbornly thinking that the process should rule the team, it should be the other way round.

Of course, bug or story, from the business side it does not matter what the team is dealing with. Both can produce an equal amount of value for the product owner.

In our team we have experimented with some techniques for estimating bugs:

1. Estimating completely unknown bugs
2. Only estimating bugs which were already analyzed
3. Allotting time for bug fixing and not estimating bugs, but rank them instead solely based on business value

With 1. we have failed misearably. For most bugs we have found 90% of the time is spent on the bug analysis. After that the bug fix can be estimated in the same way as a story. By planning the bugs into a sprint we made the mistake that the unknown scope impacted story resolution up until the point where almost every sprint we did this way failed.

Based on the 90/10 ratio (analysis to bug fixing) estimation technique option 2. did mean that we had to plan for analysis which was not something that was covered for sprint planning (we had learned from option 1, but had no real solution how to go on with analyzed bugs). The result was that bug analysis was not done since a sprint focused on the planned items instead. The team did not have time to focus on bugs from the backlog. So eventually they did not get done either.

By embracing uncertainty we have now settled on option 3. We have split up the product backlog into a regular story/task part that can be estimated by the team using story points and a bug backlog. In the bug backlog the product owner ranks bugs based on business value and very rough team judgement. The team allows for allotting a chunk of time during a sprint that it can spend on focusing on bugs. The product owner does not know the exact outcome as it was not possible to plan that anyway before. The ratio of bug backlog versus regular backlog can be adjusted for each sprint depending on the current status of each backlog and the importance and business value of the content.

By taking out the uncertainty it did free up the team again. Sprints were not compromised by unknown bugs. By separating bugs into a different backlog both increased team's regular sprint focus and made us finish bugs which contained significant business value as well.

So it depends whether story points are suitable for you. I would try to estimate bugs using story points first. If that fails try my option 3. It has made our (over 30 sprint old) team focus on older bugs again which contain great business value. It has also freed us from trying to deliver something which the team simply cannot estimate. It was embracing the unknown that got us closer to the reality and also made our sprints successful again *while* delivering a big chunk (based on the bug to story ratio) of business value through bug fixes. The ratio we used recently was 50/50.

Answer (score 5):

I have to disagree with the top answer of assigning story points to bugs. Story points should be for new value being delivered. If you are going to assign points to product value and non-value items, you might as well just estimate and track hours.

Bugs are the overhead of what you did yesterday and is not indicative of the velocity of product completion, and they don't create any new product value either (think about it). Bugs are kind of like interrupts and all the other cow pies you need to deal with on a weekly basis. The whole idea of story points is that it tracks/estimates when we will deliver the product (or feature set). Story points are arbitrary and that's how it removes all the non-value overhead from estimation. Generally the non-value work is constant week-to-week, so it is built into the team velocity. The team will accelerate when they remove or reduce this non-value work.

Put another way, why even track points to bugs? So that at the end of the day you know how much "work" each member did? Stop that! Bad manager! :)  Measure the team, not the player. Encourage the team to manage themselves if one person is not pulling their weight. Much more effective. Doing story point items should not make an individual feel better, but the team as a whole should feel better when they make their commitment at the end of the sprint. In sports, is the goal good for the team or the individual? If the individual plays for himself the team loses in the long run.

You know, eventually you want not to use points at all. Estimation is time taken away from real work. When a team reaches *maximum chi* they don't use points at all yet know exactly how many items they can pull into a sprint. They've mastered the art of breaking up units of work that estimation is process waste.

Answer (score 3):

Some tasks are estimateable, some are not.  **For things that cannot be estimated, use a budget.**

Fixing a defect is not a readily estimateable task because it has several unknown components to it.  What is causing the defect?  Once the cause is understood, how can it be fixed?  What impact does this change have on the rest of the system?  How many new defects did you inject fixing this defect?

Keep in mind that the cause of a defect can come from any point in the software lifecycle -- misunderstood or miscommunicated requirements, poor design or wrong assumptions, poor coding, bad testing, new knowledge about the problem based on information learned from the current release...

Creating a budget can be done in a couple of different ways for bug fixing tasks.  Here's some ideas I've used effectively:

- Use historical data (say from a previous iteration) to help you understand how much time to set aside for bug fixing.
- Put "blocks" of bugfixing (say 5 points or 20 hours) in your backlog and let the customer choose this in lieu of stories.
- Require that each member of your team dedicate a specified amount of time each iteration fixing defects.

Your goal is then to fix as many defects as possible within the budget allocated.  Discuss with your customer strategies for prioritizing reported defects.  For example, do you sort defects by criticality then priority?  Strict priority?  Should you attack "low-hanging fruit" first?  UI bugs first?

Also, fixing bugs does not earn value.  Fixing defects are a form of waste.  You already earned value on the feature so you should not get "bonus points" for fixing bugs.

Having a budget helps with planning and still gives you an accurate picture of Velocity.  Budget a specific number of points for bug fixing, give the budget an approximate amount of time based on your historic data, and then squash as many bugs as you can in the time budgeted!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the focus on stories and bugs and chores and the points each has, I find it better to focus on delivering features for the customer.

Customers expect the software to work and only give real value to development, enhancements and new features as these drive the business forward.

Bug fixes, as important as they may be, do not drive the business forward into new areas and new customers (tangentially and eventually perhaps yes but not immediately which is what management is measuring).

So points are best viewed from the higher viewpoint of velocity and how many points per week have been done historically for similarly scored stories.

This can lead to a management by track record history rather than pushing the urgent need for this weeks stories to be complete and frequently finding that they are not.  However the loss of up-front control and increased trust that this requires will have some managers running for the door in horror.

I use Pivotal Tracker (I've just JIRA, Trak, Trello and others too) and Pivotal Tracker also does not do points for chores or bugs.  It's done for the same good reasons above that make it also true in JIRA as you are seeing yourself.